# to check with JavaScript whether the page is displayed in a browser?

Tags: javascript, mobile

Can I check with JavaScript whether the page is displayed in a browser or as a bookmark Shortcut on the homescreen?

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear, if you mean were you click add to homescreen and you"ve made your website App aware there is the `window.navigator.standalone` flag.

Comment: I've been looking for that!
Now I have the problem that in with the window.location.replace("http://.."); command, the new page does not open in the webbrowser. How can I make that the page is opened in the webbrowser and not in the webapp?

Answer (score 0):

Almost certainly not. The only reasonable way to implement the bookmark on the home screen is to use a snapshot stored locally. Think about it: The device isn't going to visit all of those pages every time you go to the home screen; that would eat up your data transfer allowance, be slow, and irritate people. Instead, it will remember a snapshot of the page as of the last time you visited, store that locally, and use that. (For instance, that's how Chrome for Desktop's New Tab page works showing your popular destinations. That's not the exact same thing, but it's effectively the same use case — and on a desktop browser where extra data transfer isn't usually an issue.)